# Does %INC contain all dependencies

Tags: perl, module, dependencies

I'm interested in knowing which modules a script I'm working with uses (I did not write it from scratch, so I'm not sure). I know that %INC contains modules used by my script, but does it also contain modules used by those modules?

Comment: As a follow up, does %INC only contain absolutely necessary modules? I would like to run my script on a different computer and I'm hoping to minimize the number of modules I transfer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does.  Every successful `require` or `use` adds the module to `%INC`.  (This includes optional modules if they were loaded.)  Look at the pseudocode for `require` in [its documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html).

Comment: It's technically not pseudocode, but a Perl version similar to the C code. ;)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to distinguish optional from necessary modules?

Comment: Examine the code and/or documentation of the module that loaded them.  (Or rename PossiblyOptional.pm to PossiblyOptional.skip and then see if the program crashes because it can't `use PossiblyOptional;`.)

Comment: `do` adds too. (It just doesn't check `%INC` like `require` does.)